# Hub Section full width

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

How to set HubSection.Width to full width of screen?
I cannot use resolution of screen to property of HubSection like this:

```
HubSection1.Width = res.Width;
HubSection2.Width = res.Width;
HubSection3.Width = res.Width;
```

...because then I swipe-right, hub section is showing incorrect layout with fragments of another section. But when I swipe-left, all are correct.

Windows Phone 8.1

Comment: Are you aware that the `Hub` control is actually designed to show 'layout with fragments of another section' on the right hand side?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is very simple. Now I am using Pivot control.